# BizTalk 2013 R2 connect to Sybase Database through ODBC (Two connect & CDATA)

Tags: odbc, adapter, biztalk, sybase, biztalk-2013r2

I have a requirement in BizTalk to connect to sybase database.
we are using BizTalk 2013 R2. I tried all ways to connect but not successful.

1. ODBC(Twoconnect)
   Its showing up in admin console and when using add generated items in visual studio but the mysql option is not showing up in visual studio.I did install the older 5.3 my sql connector versions as the new 8 series throws an error when installing.

https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-odbc/

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12824.biztalk-server-list-of-custom-adapters.aspx#hhh
In the technet link the ODBC is supported till BizTalk 2013.

2. CDATA
   I have also tried to connect using CDATA
   https://www.cdata.com/drivers/sybase/biztalk/
   but it looks like the connection string is invalid when i try.
   I am trying to provide servername,DB name,UserID,password and port number.It says specified connecting string in Invalid.

Not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: Why were you using a mysql driver? You need a Sybase SDK which includes the appropriate driver for the Sybase product. Note that not all Sybase drivers are the same so you need the correct one for the product i.e. ASE, IQ, Anywhere.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: Thanks I will ask to download the Sybase sdk driver

Comment: That was @RichCampbell that said that, not me :-)